# PHP Loop to display unique message for each day

Tags: php, loops

I have 24 days which have unique messages each day. How could i write the following IF statements in some sort of loop to make it more efficient: -

```
<?

if ($day == '1') {

  $offerTxt = $day1Txt;

} else if ($day == '2') {

  $offerTxt = $day2Txt;

} else if ($day == '3') {

  $offerTxt = $day3Txt;

} else if ($day == '4') {

  $offerTxt = $day4Txt;

} else if ($day == '5') {

  $offerTxt = $day5Txt;

} else if ($day == '6') {

  $offerTxt = $day6Txt;

} 


?>
```

Comment: Dont use a if, use a switch statement

Comment: Try using an array ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this inline like this:

```
$offerTxt = ${'day'.$day.'Txt'};
```

You should probably check whether the day is in a certain set, so your code would come out looking similar to this:

```
$daysUsed = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$offerTxt = '';
if(in_array((int)$day, $daysUsed)) {
    $offerTxt = ${'day'.$day.'Txt'};
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use an array:

```
$array = $textforDays = array(
    1 => 'Text for day 1',
    2 => 'Text for day 2',
    3 => 'Text for day 3',
    4 => 'Text for day 4',
    5 => 'Text for day 5',
    6 => 'Text for day 6',
);
echo $textforDays[$day];
```